# Can I change the looking of html5 voice input mic?

Tags: html, voice

I know that I can make my `input` box support voice input by add an attribute `x-webkit-speech`, (you can see it in Google's search bar ), but I don't like the microphone's style, can I change it with my own image or a text?

Answer (score 0):

Check whether the element has a computed background-image style. If it does, you can change the background-image and that'll work fine. If not, then maybe you can add a background image or some kind of overlay to hide the old mic and show your own.